# Shell variable match

Tags: regex, shell, variables

I need some help with a script. I want this script to echo "Det funkar med serier" to my log file.

```
#!/bin/sh

HDFILM1=/media/store1/HD-film
HDFILM2=/media/store2/HD-film
SERIER1="/media/store0/Serier*"
SERIER2=/media/store2/Serier

LOGFILE=/home/holmen/script/rtorrent_unrar_move_files.sh.log

rm -rfv $LOGFILE
echo 2 = $2 2>&1 >> $LOGFILE
echo 3 = $3 2>&1 >> $LOGFILE

if [ $3 = $HDFILM1 ] || [ $3 = $HDFILM2 ]; then
        echo "Det funkar med filmer" 2>&1 >> $LOGFILE
elif [[ $3 =~ $SERIER1 ]]; then
        echo "Det funkar med serier" 2>&1 >> $LOGFILE
else
        echo "Det funkar INTE" 2>&1 >> $LOGFILE
fi
```

Output in the log file.

```
2 = Family.Guy.S10E08.HDTV.Custom.HebSub.XviD-Extinct
3 = /media/store0/Serier/Family_Guy
Det funkar INTE
```

As you can see i cant get the regex in the *$SERIER1* variable to work and i cant find how to solve it.

I want the if condition to match */media/store0/Serier/Family_Guy* from a regex in the variable e.g. **^/media/store0/Serier**

How do i get the if part

```
elif [[ $3 =~ $SERIER1 ]]; then
```

To work?

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) points out several issues, such as `[[ .. ]]` being undefined in `/bin/sh` (use `/bin/bash`), and `2>&1 >> $LOGFILE` not working as intended (use `>> $LOGFILE 2>&1`)

Comment: I will test /bin/bash when i get home

Comment: You are using unquoted variables inside your single-bracketed conditions which, in your specific case, may not be a problem (no filenames containing spaces), but should be quoted to be more robust.  To help debugging, try adding "#!/bin/bash -ue" as your first line to enable variable expansion checking and fail-fast on non-zero return codes.  This will often help see where problems come from by not letting failures remain silen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your `SERIER1` variable does **not** contain a regexp. It contains a glob. Globs are another pattern specification language like regexp but they are not compatible.

In glob, `*` means zero or more of anything

In regexp, `*` means zero or more of the previous character

This distinction is important. The pattern:

```
r*
```

In glob matches `rainbow` and `range` and `r`

In regexp matches `r` and `rr` and `rrrrrr`

So, the pattern you have:

```
/media/store0/Serier*
```

Will only match: `/media/store0/Serier` or `/media/store0/Serierrr` or `/media/store0/Serierrrrrrr` etc.

I presume what you want is:

```
/media/store0/Serier.*
```

Because in regexp `.` means anything. So `.*` means zero or more of anything which is equivalent to `*` in glob.

Comment: True; the OP can use a glob though with the `=` operator inside `[[ ... ]]` as well.

Comment: Thank you, so I need something like this: SERIER1=/media/store0/Serier/.* and then elif [[ $3 =~ $SERIER1 ]] am I right?

Comment: @junkyhlm Yes. Or as chepner mentioned you can also use the `=` operator with glob instead of `=~` with regexp

Comment: Thank you, will try tomorrow :)

Comment: While correct, this is not a blocker. `/media/store0/Serier/Family_Guy` matches `/media/store0/Serier*` because `=~` matches substrings